# ASP.NET Mvc jquery ui dialog as view or partialview?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, partial-views

I want to show view or partialview on dialog. There is an example in ASP.NET Mvc 4 default template (AjaxLogin.js). AjaxLogin.js catches if login is ajax. And runs jsonresult or actionresult. AjaxLogin control this with passing parameter to dialog. So passing parameter is important for me.

Is there a problem with my use of this library for my specified forms. Or is there another js library about this topic?

I m new about jquery ui. I m using AjaxLogin.js in my project now, for other forms. And they work. Should I continue to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use [**jQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/) library for the dialog. It is simple as this

**1) Add a reference to the jQuery UI library( Refer from the [CDN](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)/LocalCopy)** in the page/layout

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**2)Add a specific class to the links so that we can use that as a jQuery selector**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Email", "Details", "Customers", null, new { @class = "popupLinks" })
```

**3) Bind the Diloag functionality to those links on the DOM ready event**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".popupLinks").click(function (e) {
            var url = this.href;
            var dialog = $("#dialog");
            if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
                dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
            }
            dialog.load(
                url,
                {}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object
                function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    dialog.dialog({                       
                        close: function (event, ui) {                            
                            dialog.remove();
                        },
                        modal: true,                            
                         width: 460, resizable: false
                    });
                }
            );           
            return false;           
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Now clicking on the link will show the content of the result of `Details` action method of `Customers` controller. ( you may change this according to your scenario)

Comment: I want to pass parameter to dialog. If parameter is null it is posted to actionresultview, is not it is posted to jsonresultview. AjaxLogin.js do this. Can your code do this?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi, you can pass parameter to this action method as querystring values.

Comment: @Shyju I don't know why the dialogBox is appearing empty! If I comment the jquery part the view comes out just fine. But when I put the jquery code, the Dialog Box appears but empty!

Comment: @Laggel Is the URL returning some content ? try to access it directly in the browser

Comment: @Shyju I was trying a POST instead of a GET which was I needed. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with the functionality and it works for you, then go for it.  I haven't used the ajaxlogin.js, so I can't comment directly on it, but I have used [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) as my modal dialog for displaying partial views with great success.

Comment: The link has the licensing, but yes it is free (MIT/GPL).  As for easy to learn, I think so, but that is relative, so checkout the API and try it for yourself.

Comment: passing parameter to dialog is important for me.