# How to explictly make a GET Request in a .Load JQuery call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to load a view inside a JQueryUI Dialog.

For that I'm using the solution proposed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11365246/1354478

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".popupLinks").click(function (e) {
            var url = this.href;
            var dialog = $("#dialog");
            if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
                dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
            }
            dialog.load(
                url,
                {}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object
                function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    dialog.dialog({                       
                        close: function (event, ui) {                            
                            dialog.remove();
                        },
                        modal: true,                            
                         width: 460, resizable: false
                    });
                }
            );           
            return false;           
        });
    });
    </script>
```

But Nothing was coming out, when I checked the Console the app was doing a POST request to my app instead of a Get. The Get DO  need parameters to be executed, how can I specify it that I need a GET not a POST.

Comment: did you read comment from your code about `{}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object`?

Comment: I do feel right now like the dumbest person in the world! I did read the comment but I though that as it was empty, it was submitting the Get. My Bad! It did work when I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove empty object declaration in

`dialog.load(url, {}, functio...`

it should look like:

`dialog.load(url, functio...`

as is stated in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)