# How can I load a pop up box with a specied URL in asp.net using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to display a pop-up box once I click the "Add Component" Link. The first time it's clicked, it will display a proper dialog box, but if I click again and again it will go that URL without the pop-up box, The pop-up box contains another view page. If I close that box, it should say "Closed", and if I click "Add Component" again the pop-up should show. Here is my JavaScript and HTML Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#lnkCreate').on('click', function (e) {
                 var url = $(this).attr('href');
                $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                 title: 'Add Component',
                 autoOpen: false,
                 resizable: false,
                 height: 455,
                 width: 500,
                 show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                 modal: true,
                 draggable: true,
                 open: function () {                 
                      $(this).load(url);             
                        alert(url);
                 },            
                 close: function () {
                     $(this).dialog('close');
                     alert("closed view");
                 }
            });
    });
</script>

<p style="padding-left:18em;padding-top:1em">
    @Html.ActionLink("Add Component", "Create",null, new { id = "lnkCreate" })
</p>
```

Comment: Take a look at [ASP.NET Mvc jquery ui dialog as view or partialview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363749/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ui-dialog-as-view-or-partialview)

Comment: Your generating a link, but you do not cancel the default action - add `e.preventDefault();` as the first line in your click handler (and you probably want to revise the code so the contents of the dialog are only loaded once on the first click to improve performance)

Comment: hello Stephen, i added "e.preventDefault();" in my click handler, but once i run my Application and if i click that Action Link the page will go to hidden format. help me

Comment: @HemanthkumarNaik, What do you mean _the page will go to hidden format_?